# Integration by parts, three times

Tags: calculus

I have a basic problem with integration by part, I know the answer to c is 1/8 per solution. But I can't carry out the steps, professor mentioned intergration by parts 3 times. Can you please show me how to go from the blue to (c=1/8)?

[image]I

[image]

Comment: TABE method!!! .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I hope this is clear. I skipped details of evaluating the limits as they approach infinity (this can be done on your part) but I have the 3 "integration by parts" steps that you were seeking.

Comment: Thanks, do all these terms evaluated to 0? This is very clear, but I don't know what to do with these terms yet.

Comment: @George The terms with $y^3e^{-y}, y^2e^{-y}$, etc. go to 0 as y approaches infinity as well as when y approaches 0. Write these as $\frac{y^3}{e^y}, \frac{y^2}{e^y}$, etc. and take the limits to see this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to work along for problem again with the steps you shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much. https://s27.postimg.org/ejhtky877/IMG_0009.png

Comment: @George no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am getting your question correctly. You are trying to calculate
$$I:=\int\mathrm e^{-y} y^3 \; \mathrm d y.$$
Set $u'= \mathrm e^{-y}$ and $v=y^3$. Integration by parts gives $\int u'v= uv - \int u v' $ that is 
$$ I=-\mathrm e^{-y} y^3 + 3\int  \mathrm e^{-y} y^2 \; \mathrm d y. $$
Now you have to integrate 
$$I_1:=\int  \mathrm e^{-y} y^2 \;\mathrm d y$$
by parts again which gives you
$$I_1 = -\mathrm e^{-y} 3y^2 + 2\int  \mathrm e^{-y} y \;\mathrm d y. $$
Set 
$$I_2 :=\int  \mathrm e^{-y} y \;\mathrm d y$$
and integrate again by parts. Hence you get
$$I_2= -\mathrm e^{-y} y+ \int \mathrm e^{-y} \; \mathrm d y = -\mathrm e^{-y} (y+1) .$$
Finally you get (collecting all the results)
$$I = -\mathrm e^{-y} \left(y^3 +2y^2 +6x +6 \right)$$
and 
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-y} y^3 \; \mathrm d y=6.$$

**Hint:** In my opinion it is better to put 
$$ -e^{-y} (ay^3 +by^2 +cy +d)$$
as a possible primitive and solve for the coefficients $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Thanks, after you get to the last line, what method would you use to solve the 3rd degree polynomial?

Comment: @George What polynomial do you mean? What do yo mean by _solve_?